# how to set width of piechart in dc.js through css

Tags: javascript, css, width, media-queries, dc.js

I want to set width of piechart of dc.js different for different resolution; for that I want to set width of piechart through css so that I can apply mediaqueries for different resolution.
   Please provide me solution for setting width of piechart of dc.js through css.

```
icd9Pie /* dc.pieChart('#gain-loss-chart', 'chartGroup') */
        // (_optional_) define chart width, `default = 200`

          .width(180) // (optional) define chart height, `default = 200`
          .height(160)

        // Define pie radius
        .radius(80)
        // Set dimension
        .dimension(icd9Dimension)
        // Set group
        .group(icd9Group)
        // (_optional_) by default pie chart will use `group.key` as

        // its label but you can overwrite it with a closure.
        .label(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        }).renderLabel(true)
        /
```

//new code

```
 icd9Pie /* dc.pieChart('#gain-loss-chart', 'chartGroup') */
        // (_optional_) define chart width, `default = 200`

          .minWidth(180) // (optional) define chart height, `default = 200`
          .minHeight(160)

        // Define pie radius
        .radius(80)
        // Set dimension
        .dimension(icd9Dimension)
        // Set group
        .group(icd9Group)
        // (_optional_) by default pie chart will use `group.key` as

        // its label but you can overwrite it with a closure.
        .label(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        }).renderLabel(true)
        /
```

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950076/media-queries-not-working-on-dc-js-chart - what about that solution doesn't work here? Please edit your question with more specifics.

Comment: It is piechart and there is no solution for setting its width value through CSS.if I remove width and parameter as like previous solution,its taking default 200px width and 200px height,how I dont know.I removed parameters and set width and height Through CSS,then also its showing svg width 200px and height px.

Comment: In style of page its showing like ,@media (max-width: 1280px)
#icd9-pie svg {
    width: 180px !important;
    height: 160px !important;
}                                                                                                            but taking svg width 200 only,when I change this width from style its affecting also in svg 
    height: 160px !important;

Comment: But you still have to apply it to the div not the SVG. I think.it should be the same answer.

Comment: I tried that also.Although applying css to div,its taking svg height and width 200px only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be just running into the minimum sizing parameters there, `minWidth` and `minHeight` - by default they are 200.

[Docs for minWidth and minHeight](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+minWidth)

The media query didn't work as you specified it above, I had to add braces. This totally worked for me:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #test { width: 180px !important; height: 160px !important; }
}
```

And set `minWidth` and `minHeight` in order to allow them to go lower than 200:

```
chart.minWidth(100)
   .minHeight(100)
```

Comment: I have given braces in my code for media-queries.Media-queries are working but yes,you are right its taking minium-height 200 only.If I tried to set height below 200 its getting set for div but taking svg height 200px only

Comment: I have checked whole code,dc.js,d3.js but I did not find any setting of min-height or max-height in code

Comment: I mean the min and max height in the dc.js API, see the documentation linked above. They default to 200, so you'll need to set them if you want smaller. I'll add sample code above.

Comment: But for scatterplot and piechart I dont know why same is not working.code is something different in syntax. I have added code above

Comment: I have added code above of minheight and in css I have given height to div 160px.then also its taking svg height 100px

Comment: It did or it didn't work for the pie chart? I'm confused.